# How to implement a flexbox-based list that scrolls once it reaches its parents size

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, grid

Im trying to implement a list of items, that correctly fits into my layout. I'd like the list to be scrollable if its intrinsic content size exceeds its parent element's dimensions. As you can see in the snippet below, instead of scrolling my list resizes hence ignoring the `overflow: scroll rule`. So far I've tried to manipulate the `overflow(-y), maxHeight, height, flex-grow, shrink` and `basis` properties but did not manage to solve my problem. Im may be only one style-rule but so far I did not manage to prevent the list from overgrowing and thereby destroying the layout.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```css
.layout {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; 
  column-gap: 10px; 
  row-gap: 10px; 
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightGrey;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.leading-upper {
  grid-column-start: 1; 
  grid-column-end: 2; 
  grid-row-start: 1; 
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.leading-lower {
  grid-column-start: 1; 
  grid-column-end: 2; 
  grid-row-start: 2; 
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.trailing {
  grid-column-start: 2; 
  grid-column-end: 3; 
  grid-row-start: 1; 
  grid-row-end: 3; 
}

.header {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.list {
  overflow: scroll;
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: column nowrap; 
  row-gap: 10px; 
  padding: 10px; 
  overflow: scroll;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="container leading-upper"></div>
  <div class="container leading-lower"></div>
  <div class="container trailing">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trailing` class should be the `flexbox` container and not the `list` class. Just put the following three lines in the `trailing` class and it almost works.

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
row-gap: 10px;
```

In the `list` class, remove one `overflow: scroll` and change the other to `overflow-y: scroll` as horizontal scrolling is not required.

There is no gap between `item`'s so add `margin-bottom: 10px;`, for example.

```css
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.container {
  background-color: lightGrey;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.leading-upper {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.leading-lower {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.trailing {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 10px;
}

.header {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.list {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="container leading-upper"></div>
  <div class="container leading-lower"></div>
  <div class="container trailing">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution! Is there any way I could use the flexbox directly? Maybe I‘m not undertanding flexbox, but I‘d like to manage layout parameters such as gap by manipulating the container, not the items itself.